# How to use full webpath in openssl

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl

Using openssl 1.1.1l:
In the command line if I type:

> openssl s_client -connect example.com:443

I can connect to my website and see my wesite's certification. However I if I were to type:

> openssl s_client -connect example.com/foo:443

I would recieve an error saying Name or service not known. Am I able to use openssl to connect to a perticular page from a website?

Comment: After connecting, you can type `GET /foo`. But `openssl` is the wrong client for this purpose. You should consider `curl` or `wget`.

Comment: curl receives the page correctly, I was attempting to test if I could use openssl to connect to a certain webpage over ssl. Eventually, I would need to implement c code to run to the example.com/foo page and pull the data from the webpage over ssl.

Comment: `libcurl` provides APIs to get the data.  See: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/simplessl.html

Comment: Perhaps libcurl is the better option I will look into that.